# JPA trying to remove entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using a method to save a object in database, see:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void movimentarCaixa(String descricao,
        AbstractBean donoCaixa, FormaPagamento formaPagamento, HistoricoPagamento historicoPagamento, double valor) {
    try {       

        HistoricoCaixa historicoCaixa;

        if (donoCaixa instanceof Dentista) {
        logger.info("Iniciando movimentacao caixa para Dentista. Valor: "+valor);
        historicoCaixa = new HistoricoCaixaDentista();
        ((Dentista) donoCaixa).setCaixaSaldoAtual(((Dentista) donoCaixa).getCaixaSaldoAtual()
                + valor);
        ((HistoricoCaixaDentista) historicoCaixa).setDentista((Dentista) donoCaixa);

        } else if (donoCaixa instanceof Paciente) {
        logger.info("Iniciando movimentacao caixa para Paciente. Valor: "+valor);
        historicoCaixa = new HistoricoCaixaPaciente();
        ((Paciente) donoCaixa).setCaixaSaldoAtual(((Paciente) donoCaixa).getCaixaSaldoAtual()
                + valor);
        ((HistoricoCaixaPaciente) historicoCaixa).setPaciente((Paciente) donoCaixa);

        } else if (donoCaixa instanceof Clinica) {
        logger.info("Iniciando movimentacao caixa para Clinica. Valor: "+valor);
        historicoCaixa = new HistoricoCaixaClinica();
        Clinica clinica = (Clinica) donoCaixa;

        if (formaPagamento == null || formaPagamento.getCodigo().equals("DINHEIRO")){
            clinica.setSaldoDinheiro(clinica.getSaldoDinheiro() + valor);       
        } else if (formaPagamento.getCodigo().equals("CHEQUE")) {
            clinica.setSaldoCheque(clinica.getSaldoCheque() + valor);
        } else if (formaPagamento.getCodigo().equals("DEBITO")) {
            clinica.setSaldoDebito(clinica.getSaldoDebito() + valor);
        } else if (formaPagamento.getCodigo().equals("CREDITO")) {
            clinica.setSaldoCredito(clinica.getSaldoCredito() + valor);
        }

        ((HistoricoCaixaClinica) historicoCaixa).setClinica((Clinica) donoCaixa);

        } else {
        throw new MyException(
                "O parametro 'donoCaixa' deve ser do tipo Dentista, Paciente ou Clinica");
        }

        historicoCaixa.setDataHora(historicoPagamento.getDataHora());
        historicoCaixa.setDescricao(descricao);
        historicoCaixa.setFormaPagamento(formaPagamento);
        historicoCaixa.setHistoricoPagamento(historicoPagamento);
        historicoCaixa.setUsuario((Usuario) SessionContext.getInstance().getUsuarioLogado());
        historicoCaixa.setValor(valor);

        this.getDao().save(historicoCaixa);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

I call this method twice, in the first time the variable "historicoCaixa" receives "new HistoricoCaixaPaciente()" instance and in second time this same variable receives "new HistoricoCaixaClinica()". The problem is that in second call i got error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance br.com.odontonew.financeiro.bean.HistoricoCaixaClinica#94
```

I imagine that JPA is trying to remove HistoricoCaixaClinica#94 but i don't want this, how can i avoid it ?

Comment: Are you sure that this error occurs when you call the same save method second time? The error says that its trying to remove the detached instance of the class. Can you attach the complete stack trace and the code where you call this method twice?

Comment: Seeing entity classes would help as well. It may be related to cascading. Also REQUIRED is a bad choice. Can you keep your transactions in one place e.g. at some service facade level to make sure both operations belong to the same transaction.

Comment: thanks, i removed cascade and its works.